# Click a link and use window.open() blocks one of the links

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, popup

I'm trying to create a simple JS function that will open a new window/tab when clicking a specific button, so the user will actually open 2 windows/tabs, however no matter what I do, one of the links gets blocked by Chrome as a "popup-blocked".

I'd like to do something like this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").mousedown(function(){
            window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/","_blank");
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://google.com">Click Me!</a>
```

;

But when I do this, the button link doesn't work, but the JS does.
If I change the JS and add a `setTimeout()` to it, the button URL goes through but the JS gets blocked.
No matter what I do, I can't get both of them to go through.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Navigating to two places at once, with one in a new window, is really popular with people who want to show the user a massive advert in a new window.

Massive adverts are unpopular with users, so browsers take steps to prevent this behaviour.

Sometimes legitimate uses get caught in the crossfire. Blame the blackhat end of the advertising industry.

---

You'll need to find some other way to display… whatever it is you want to display… to the user that doesn't involve navigating to multiple webpages at the same time in separate windows.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is caused by the mousedown() event you are using which is a part of down+up sequence to trigger the click() event of the `<a>` tag.

so opening a new window "breaks" the flow and browser is not tracking for the mouse-up event anymore to follow the original url.

so the solution is to attach the click() event instead without stopping propagation. this will fire the attached and original events and none of them will be blocked.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/","_blank");
        });
    })
```

you can try sample on [this page](https://delphir.com/test.html) as stackoverflow snippet is sandboxed and is blocking popups

Comment: Tried that obviously. Same outcome unfortunately.

Comment: then your question is incomplete as my code working as expected

Comment: "so the user will actually open 2 windows/tabs" - this is the issue.

Comment: so like I said your question is incomplete. you didn't provide the sample html, you are not sure if you with to open a "new tab" or a "new window" and your question clearly states that only one of two links gets loaded with your code. So I provided you with a solution to load both.

Comment: and just in case if you really not just want to load the both pages, but also both of them to be a "new tabs" - then this is not possible. Modern browsers do prevent any malware-like activity and each new window can be opened only by following a user interaction (like a mouse-click). So you waste your first click on one popup, and ... you can't fire two user-clicks with one mouse click, so the second one is blocked by the browser.